# Logged in user information doesn't populate profile fields

Tags: wordpress, contacts, profile

Perhaps there's an easy way out of this - so I'll keep the details down (for now).

1. A new user signs in to Wordpress and
2. CiviCRM reliably adds this user's email to the contacts.
3. The user gets redirected to a page with a CiviCRM profile on it to get more information on the user.

-> The information entered does not populate the new CiviCRM contact, but adds a new one OR if one enters the user's email address it signals that there's a duplicate entry.

Now the documentation says:

> For websites that have logged-in users, you may want to allow people to provide additional information as they register for an account on your website. Similarly, when people fill out a profile form you may want to encourage (or force) them to sign up for a user account.

Latter works (in a different use case); but it's the former option that fails - no matter what I try to tweek in the settings.

Cheers

Stefan

Answer (score 1):

I'd added the CiviCRM profile via the button to add short code - and skipped over the obvious:

[image]

Click "Edit" instead of "Create".

I didn't find the mistake until I read over short code I'd inserted, which read:

```
[civicrm component="profile" gid="18" mode="create" hijack="0"]
```

and should have:

```
[civicrm component="profile" gid="18" mode="edit" hijack="0"]
```

Cheeers

Comment: As a note, I believe when the profile is in `Edit` mode Civi will throw an error for non authenticated users